# .htaccess RewriteRule works on one page not another (PHP upgrade)

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, php-5.6, php-7.4

I have a website on which .htaccess is used.
I tried to move this site to another server, but found, that some RewriteRules are not working.

My .htaccess file content is below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^checkout/?$ index.php?c=order&a=checkout&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
...
```

This rule is working on the current server (PHP 5.6), but isn't working on new server (PHP 7.4).
The rule should rewrite url:
`https://mywebsite.com/checkout/?pm=CreditCard&brand=MasterCard&paymentMethodId=1\`
to:
`https://mywebsite.com/index.php?c=order&a=checkout&`**pm=CreditCard&brand=MasterCard&paymentMethodId=1**

The text in bold should be copied from the first URL, but it only shows index.php file on a new server (sessions and cookies are cleaned / incognito, I'm not logged).

Is there something changed in the newest PHP version? or what can I do to make it work? :)

Comment: Try using the [QSA] flag, something like so: `RewriteRule ^checkout/?$ index.php?c=order&a=checkout [QSA]`

Comment: Thanks. This answer guide me to real problem.
The problem was in some Apache configuration.

Actually the query_string was passed correctly by the .htaccess, but the script was working different in this environment.

Comment: On this new server with PHP 7.4, the `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING']` has the old value (before rewrite rule), but on the old server, there was correct value.
On the server with PHP 7.4 this correct value was under `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`, so I have to use QUERY_STRING.
Maybe there is some configuration which changes this behavior in Apache, but couldn't find it.